# Minimum number of real repeated roots of the following function are?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $g(x)=f’(x)$ The given figure represents the graph of $y=g(x), a\leq x \leq b$ . Given $f(c)=0$ Find the minimum number of repeated roots.[image]

Since the function is always decreasing so it crosses the x axis only once at c. Therefore there is only one root ?

Comment: From the image $\frac{d}{dx}f(c)=0$ but is $f(c)$ also zero (taken from the text)? Is the function a Polynomial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is given that $f(c)=0$. Since $f$ is strict monotonic, we have $f(x) \ne 0$ for all $x \in [a,b] \setminus\{c\}.$

From the image we see that $f'(c)=0$ and $f''(c) = 0.$ Hence $f$ has a zero of order $ \ge 3$ at $c$.

Comment: OOps. I edited my answer.